# There is no user session data for the user within the specified date range

Tags: powershell

I am using the following query to retrieve user session information within a specified date range from o365 skype for business service.

```
$mbxes = Get-CsOnlineUser | select UserPrincipalName
$startTime = "5/1/2018"
foreach ($mbx in $mbxes) {
  Get-CsUserSession -User $mbx -StartTime $startTime
}
```

Running this query gives me the following warnings for all mailboxes that I am retrieving:

```
WARNING: There is no user session data for the user @{UserPrincipalName=account1@companyX.onmicrosoft.com} within the specified date range 01/05/2018 00:00:00 -07:00 to
11/06/2018 05:22:31 -07:00.
```

However when I am simply running this command:

```
$mbxes = "account1@companyX.onmicrosoft.com"
$startTime = "5/1/2018"
foreach ($mbx in $mbxes) {
  Get-CsUserSession -User $mbx -StartTime $startTime
}
```

I am getting all sessions data responding to this mailbox.
I am wondering why when I am making a variable with all the mailbox address is not giving me back data even though, session data exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your first command you include `| select UserPrincipalName`. This will assign `$mboxes` as an array of objects that only have the `UserPrincipalName` property.

From the second command, it looks like `Get-CsUserSession` expects the `-User` parameter to be a string, but you're still passing an object. You can probably solve with any of the below:

Expand the `UserPrincipalName` as a string, then you have a string array:

```
$mbxes = Get-CsOnlineUser | select -ExpandProperty UserPrincipalName
$startTime = "5/1/2018"
foreach ($mbx in $mbxes) {
  Get-CsUserSession -User $mbx -StartTime $startTime
}
```

Another method of expanding to get an array of strings:

```
$mbxes = (Get-CsOnlineUser).UserPrincipalName
$startTime = "5/1/2018"
foreach ($mbx in $mbxes) {
  Get-CsUserSession -User $mbx -StartTime $startTime
}
```

Explicitly select the property when getting the session:

```
$mbxes = Get-CsOnlineUser | select UserPrincipalName
$startTime = "5/1/2018"
foreach ($mbx in $mbxes) {
  Get-CsUserSession -User $mbx.UserPrincipalName -StartTime $startTime
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The User: `@{UserPrincipalName=account1@companyX.onmicrosoft.com}` is not a valid userPrincipalName,

Change this:

```
$mbxes = Get-CsOnlineUser | select UserPrincipalName
```

To:

```
$mbxes = Get-CsOnlineUser | select -Expand UserPrincipalName
```

see: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2009/09/13/select-expandproperty-propertyname/

Comment: Or use `(Get-CsOnlineUser).UserPrincipalName`

Comment: @Avshalom Thanks a lot for your answer!